# When I use primitives for Object.assign(), the results are presented as empty objects

Tags: javascript

I don't understand the 'Primitives will be wrapped to objects' part of example.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Primitives_will_be_wrapped_to_objects

The example shows that the primitives will be wrapped, but the result is an empty object.

```js
var v1 = true;
var v2 = 10;
var v3 = Symbol('foo');

console.log(Object.assign({}, v1, v2, v3)); //ouput: {}
```

Is the result because primitives are ignored like null and undefined?

What does this example mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, every parameter past the first will be converted [to an object](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object.assign), but primitives do not have any enumerable own-properties by default:

> 1. Let from be ToObject(nextSource).
> 2. Let keys be from.[OwnPropertyKeys].
> 3. (iterate over keys, assign them to the first argument object)

(The properties you can access on some primitives are either on the prototype, and not own keys (like `toFixed`) or non-enumerable (like `length`), so they don't get included)

So, the resulting object has no key-value pairs, because neither the boolean, the string, nor the symbol had any enumerable own-properties.

If you explicitly used `new <primitiveType>` and assigned a property to the resulting wrapped object, you *would* see the property in the result:

```js
var v1 = new Boolean(true); // please don't ever do this in real code
v1.foo = 'foo';
var v2 = 10;
var v3 = Symbol('foo');

console.log(Object.assign({}, v1, v2, v3));
```

Comment: MDN example says that "Only string wrappers can have own enumerable properties.". But your answer says that "String had no any own-properties.". Does that mean different things?
And there's one more question.
I understood in Object.assign() that the primitive type cannot be converted to an object because it does not have its own properties. Am I right?

Comment: The string is like a char array, and the array is an object, where the index of array is his key. So, because that, the string can have own enumerable properties. Example `var s = 'abc'; console.log(s[0])`.

Comment: @EduardoGarcia I understood. Thank you :)